# Moodle scheduler that allows students to book a slot

Tags: php, scheduler, moodle

I need to modify the Moodle scheduler so that the students can book a slot for a selected event (ex. Tests, Exams etc.).

Where should I modify the code and what do I need to change?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Hi [Vladimir](https://stackoverflow.com/users/20332842/vladimir)
I would recommend you to use the [Organizer](https://moodle.org/plugins/mod_organizer) activity by the AMC Academic Moodle Cooperation since Scheduler just allows you to book slots with a (single) lecturer.

Best,
Luca